# How to back test pairs trading strategies in R

Tags: r, trading, quantitative-finance, performanceanalytics, back-testing

I am trying to learn about pairs trading strategy and I am using this [pseudo code](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/28043/16754) for writing my R programme.

```
if X and Y are cointegrated:
    calculate Beta between X and Y 
    calculate spread as X - Beta * Y
    calculate z-score of spread

    # entering trade (spread is away from mean by two sigmas):
    if z-score > 2:
        sell spread (sell 1000 of X, buy 1000 * Beta of Y)
    if z-score < -2:
        buy spread (buy 1000 of X, sell 1000 * Beta of Y)

    # exiting trade (spread converged close to mean):
    if we're short spread and z-score < 1:
        close the trades
    if we're long spread and z-score > -1:
        close the trades

# repeat above on each new bar, recalculating rolling Beta and spread etc.
```

I am currently using `Systematic Investor Toolbox (SIT)`  for backtesting using technical analysis but I dont know how to do backtest pair trading strategies using SIT.

```
#data downloading
library(quantmod)

#downloading cointegrated pepsi and coca cola time series data from yahoo
pep<-getSymbols("PEP",start="2010-01-01",auto.assign=F)
ko<-getSymbols("KO",start="2010-01-01",auto.assign=F)

#close price of pepsi and coca cola
pepc<-Cl(pep)
koc<-Cl(ko)

#rolling regression of close price of pepsi vs coca cola
reg= rollSFM(pepc,koc , 50)


#calculating spread
spread=pepc-reg$beta*koc

#mean of the spread
avg=mean(spread)

#standard deviation of spread
std=sd(spread)

#z-score
z=(spread-avg)/std

#pair trading longing and shorting
if(z> 2){
  sell spread()
  t=1
} else if(z<-2) {
  buy spread()
  t=2
}
else if(z<1&t=1) {
  close the short trade
}else if(z>-1&t=2) {
  close the long trade
}
```

The current problem is how to simulate buying and selling of pairs in SIT. If SIT cant do pairs trading strategy back testing then how should I perform pairs trading strategy especially entering and exiting. What logic should I use?

EDIT

After searching a while I know that we can make a backtester from scratch using `PerformanceAnalytics`; but before back testing we have to create signal and return values. Below is a sample code

```
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

s <- get(getSymbols('SPY'))["2016::"]
s$sma20 <- SMA(Cl(s) , 20)
s$signal <- ifelse(Cl(s) > s$sma20 , 1 , -1)
myReturn <- lag(s$signal) * dailyReturn(s)
charts.PerformanceSummary(cbind(dailyReturn(s),myReturn))
```

In the above code creating signal is easy but for pairs trading what logic should I use for creating signals and return for that signals?